# Qt OpenCV Static Release Build App crashes after I tried to read frame from Video Capture

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, video-capture, avi

I got an interesting problem. After few week I spend to bring my Qt and OpenCv to static build I realized, when I tried to read frame from VideoCapture - from .avi file, my program had crashed all the time. VideoCapture with WebCamera works perfect. VideoCapture.Open() - returns 1 - no problem. Can anybody help me please?

Crash : 
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: PrehravanieVidea.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    51e39027
  Fault Module Name:    msvcrt.dll
  Fault Module Version: 7.0.7600.16385
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4a5bda6f
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0000a048
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1051
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

My code :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDir>
#include <QFileDialog>



MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
   // inicializacia ////////////////////////






}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{

   QDir directory = QDir::currentPath();

    QString path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName (this, tr("Directory"), directory.path());
    if ( path.isNull() == false )
    {
        directory.setPath(path);
    }
    ui->console->appendPlainText(path);



   video_cap.open(path.toStdString());
   if(!video_cap.isOpened()){ui->console->appendPlainText("I can't open the file!");}
   else {ui->console->appendPlainText("Video file is opened!");

 video_cap.read(video_frame);



  video_cap.release();


   }
}
```

.pro file :

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-07-14T11:33:32
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = PrehravanieVidea
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui


CONFIG += exceptions
INCLUDEPATH +=C:/opencv/build/include
LIBS += -LC:\\opencv\\mybuild\\lib \
-lopencv_contrib246 \
-lopencv_stitching246 \
-lopencv_nonfree246 \
-lopencv_superres246 \
-lopencv_ts246 \
-lopencv_videostab246 \
-lopencv_gpu246 \
-lopencv_legacy246 \
-lopencv_ml246 \
-lopencv_objdetect246 \
-lopencv_calib3d246 \
-lopencv_photo246 \
-lopencv_video246 \
-lopencv_features2d246 \
-lopencv_highgui246 \
-llibjasper \
-lIlmImf \
-llibtiff \
-llibpng \
-llibjpeg \
-lopencv_flann246 \
-lopencv_imgproc246 \
-lopencv_core246 \
-lzlib \
-lzlib \
-lopencv_haartraining_engine
LIBS += -LC:\\ProgramFiles\\MicrosoftSDKs\\Windows\\v7.0\\Lib \
-lVfw32 \
-lmsvfw32 \
-lComCtl32 \
-lGdi32
```